# Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource. How to fix

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I don't know but when I close the project and then open it this id is changed.constrains::OrestHutovych was: 9:8df671e96368d2e485f0166207cc5e73

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 changesets check sum
          db/changelog/0.0.1/changelog-create-identity-schema.sql::add-user_accounts_roles-table-constrains::OrestHutovych was: 9:8df671e96368d2e485f0166207cc5e73 but is now: 9:08a7c0401b617afbb4e89a5b2843b6e0

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1231) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at com.example.twitterdemo.TwitterDemoApplication.main(TwitterDemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 changesets check sum
          db/changelog/0.0.1/changelog-create-identity-schema.sql::add-user_accounts_roles-table-constrains::OrestHutovych was: 9:8df671e96368d2e485f0166207cc5e73 but is now: 9:08a7c0401b617afbb4e89a5b2843b6e0

    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:237) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$0(Liquibase.java:222) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:184) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:193) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:183) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:162) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:1371) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:211) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:193) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:331) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:286) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 changesets check sum
          db/changelog/0.0.1/changelog-create-identity-schema.sql::add-user_accounts_roles-table-constrains::OrestHutovych was: 9:8df671e96368d2e485f0166207cc5e73 but is now: 9:08a7c0401b617afbb4e89a5b2843b6e0

    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:353) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.command.core.helpers.DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.run(DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.java:92) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:214) ~[liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

The stackTrace that you get tells you where is the problem:

> Caused by: liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException:
> liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
> 1 changesets check sum
> db/changelog/0.0.1/changelog-create-identity-schema.sql::add-user_accounts_roles-table-constrains::OrestHutovych
> was: 9:8df671e96368d2e485f0166207cc5e73 but is now:
> 9:08a7c0401b617afbb4e89a5b2843b6e0

The problem is in `add-user_accounts_roles-table-constrains` `.sql` file: you have changed the `.sql` that you have defined before in this file and now when you are rerunning the application the check sum of file is different you have in `DATABASECHANGELOG` table in your database.

1. As a first solution: rollback the changes from this file and create another one where you will define the newest changes.
2. Do an update in `databasechangelog` table where you will update `MD5SUM` column value to `08a7c0401b617afbb4e89a5b2843b6e0` based on `FILENAME` column.

But I really recommend to follow first solution because the main usage of `liquibase` is a **VERSION OF CONTROL** of `database` structure.